# REstSharp good practice

Tags: restsharp

Sorry in advance for the newbie question but I'm not a c# dev and nor a web dev but I have to develop a service that will send data every 5 mn to a webApi hosted by a dreamfactory portal.

Until now I managed to create the client and the reauest using the RestSharp framework. I succeed to have a token given back by the server.

Now I need to use the same client in an infinite loop that will pick up some data from a database and send it to the server.

My question is quite simple, must a create (new) a new request at each iteration or can I use the same request object ?

Comment: Why not simply try if you can reuse the `Request` object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it from another forum, just iterate on a new request object hoping that the garbage collectore will do it's job.